# Display 7 segment HDSP-N101

Tags: arduino, 7segmentdisplay

I'm new in electronics and I have a doubt. Recently I bought a 7 segment display to practice with Arduino, but I don't know how it works. I have searched at the [Datasheet](http://www.diotronic.com/docs/hdsph101.pdf):

[image]

[image]

I suppose that my display is T because it is write in it "HDSP-N101" an I looked the first table of the Datasheet:

My question is:

I have to connect all cathodes to earth (because they are the negative part) with a resistance of 220 ohms?

And then, I connect the anodes to the pins of Arduino to create the numbers? Because there are 4 anode pins. With this 4 pins, how can I show a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suppose that my display is T because it is write in it "HDSP-N101" an I looked the first table of the Datasheet

Yes.

> I have to connect all cathodes to earth (because they are the negative 
>   part) with a resistance of 220 ohms?
>
> And then, I connect the anodes to the pins of Arduino to create the
>   numbers? Because there are 4 anode pins. With this 4 pins, how can I
>   show a number?

No. That display is a Common-Anode display, i.e. all the LEDs share the same anode. 
You must connect the Anode to VCC, and the cathodes (each one with a separate resistor, 220-330 Ohm) to the Arduino, to display the numbers (i.e. by lighting the segments corresponding to the number). For instance, to display a 1, light segments b and c.

Each cathode controls a segment or the right decimal point. See picture below taken from your datasheet.

[image]

Comment: But in the table it says that there are 4 anodes (4, 6, 12, 17). I have to connect this four to Vcc?

Comment: Can u figure out that decimal point? I'm still scratching my head at that part of the drawing. Or is that just a smudge under the DP... / pin 11

Comment: @Trevor It's just a bad scan of the hardcopy :) Pin 10 is the DP's cathode, pin 11 is D's cathode.

Comment: @albert As you can see from the schematics, the anodes are in common, so, in theory you could choose anyone of them. Still, even if the current per each segment is low, maybe you should connect all (most) of them to VDD/VCC, to reduce the current for each anode...

Comment: @Trevor now I saw that I exactly posted the same picture of yours, later than you :) +1.

Comment: Where I have to connect earth? Or I don't have to do? because the circuit has to close

Comment: @albert The segments will turn on when your arduino outputs a low voltage. In this case, the current will make this way to ground (not earth): 5V->LED->Resistor->ArduinoPin (i.e. the microcontroller)->Ground. In other words, you don't have to connect this display to ground, your arduino outputs will give the "low" voltage.

Comment: I have tried to write a 1 and it worked. I only need to connect 1 anode to Vcc. I see that Arduino has to write LOW to the pins to light the segments. It is because it is annode. Thanks!

Comment: @albert if you only connect one anode to Vcc you may notice a significant brightness difference between characters... especially "8" and "1". Multiple anode pins (Or Vcc/ GND etc.) is usually a sign that you need to connect them all so power is properly distributed across the device.

Answer (score 4):

Look further down in the spec-sheet. The internal wiring is shown as follows...

(something seems off about the DP though...)

[image]

NOTE: The anodes are all common and connected together via multiple pins to share the current. Your Arduino needs to pull down the appropriate cathodes through appropriate resistors in the right combinations to show the symbols you desire.